# Windows 10 logs event id 98 volume recovery every second "No action required"

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, event-log

An example:

Logboeknaam:   System

Bron:          Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs

Datum:         20-02-08 20:30:56

Gebeurtenis-id:98

Taakcategorie: Geen

Niveau:        Informatie

Beschrijving: Volume Recovery (\Device\HarddiskVolume2) is in orde. U hoeft geen actie te ondernemen.

It is going on for two days now  (maybe longer).

Don't like it

It seems \HarddiskVolume2 isn't a serious volume according to sysinternals

[image: it seems \HarddiskVolume2 isn't a serious volume according to sysinternals]

Comment: I would Back up critical data Now, see what the SMART data says about the health of the drive, replace the drive if it is failing.

Comment: I did. In the mean time I found out that this occurred after a restart after power failure. And the Volume2 is assigned to "Q:", an unused memorycard slot, also connected to Volume6. So I would like to "delete" Volume2 but that is not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching with WinObj it looks like HarddiskVolume2 is not a double of a card-slot but the bootpartition on harddisk0. So it's impossible to run anything like chkdsk on it. I put in a Memory card in one slot, this seemed to stop it. However after some time logging started again (every 7 seconds in stead of every 1) After restart for updating it seems stopped all together. I was told later that there was a power issue and a hard reboot that seems to have started it.